# How can I play a youtube video in a windows 8 store app (javascript)

Tags: javascript, windows-8, youtube

I've tried a lot of different solutions on the web but none seem to work. Given a youtube key "8sPj0Ic8KQ8" I want to play the video in a Windows 8 metro-style javascript app.

Simple ,  and  tags do not work, no surprise there. My next stop was the Player Framework for Windows 8 Metro Style Applications and Smooth Streaming Client SDK. The examples work since they point to an mp4 file but when I paste a youtube url into the example even that doesn't work.

Next, I noticed there is a "MyTools" framework out there but it's only for C#/Xaml and not javascript. Furthermore the code is not supplied, only DLLs so I don't think converting it is an option.

I also tried WinJS.Utilities.setInnerHTMLUnsafe() suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507557/playing-youtube-video-in-windows-8-app) - just get a white box, no video.

Finally, I queried youtube directly for the full page contents and I've been attempting to parse out the mp4 URI myself... without much luck. I also found a PHP library to do what I'm attempting but after converting it to javascript it seems it's either really old or just doesn't work right.

I also tried "?html5=1" in an iframe suggested by this book: [Start Here windows 8 with HTML](http://books.google.com/books?id=trZCAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT296&lpg=PT296&dq=windows%208%20WinJS.Application.sessionState&source=bl&ots=h-yzda7LKg&sig=sUYx6WCvbRjL5adNq6NXV9QC0A8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SM45VIPzD4zoggSDhoEI&ved=0CEoQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=windows%208%20WinJS.Application.sessionState&f=false)

If anyone has another suggestion I haven't tried or if you've successfully played a youtube video in a javascript metro app I'd be very interested to hear how you did it. Thank you.

UPDATE: I've now been able to successfully extract the mp4 file data from a youtube page. This will let me download the stream to my computer but I'm still unable to play it in a Windows 8 app, all I get is a white box with no controls or error messages. I want users to see videos, not save them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this. The answer is to A) parse the actual URI from the youtube page. B) Use the Microsoft.SmoothStreaming library in combination with a C) video tag. This got youtube videos to play for me in Windows metro style app. If you need help with part A, this site helped me a lot: [How to grab youtube playback video files](http://coding-everyday.blogspot.com/2013/03/how-to-grab-youtube-playback-video-files.html)